# Angular 8 cannot match nested route

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 8 and am having trouble trying to get a nested route to work. The error I get is:

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'product/colours'

I have the AppComponent HTML which loads my child component 'product' without issue.

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Inside my 'product' component I want to include a nested component called 'colours'.

**colours.component.html**

```
<a routerLinkActive="is-active" routerLink="colours">Colours</a>
<router-outlet name="nested"></router-outlet>
```

I added a new nested route like this:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
  {
    path: 'product',
    component: ProductComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'colours',
        component: ColoursComponent,
        outlet: 'nested'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Any advice?

Comment: do you need the named outlet for some reason? is there also a primary outlet in there forcing you to use a named outlet?

Comment: I think you need something like `/product/colours` otherwise it will match just `/colours`.

Comment: I have a primary outlet in the same view. If I have to define multiple routes without an outlet then I will have to duplicate template code for each `product/[nested]' view.

Comment: unclear what you mean by "view"... it's fine for a parent to have a primary outlet and a child to have one as well, it's fairly common.  You only NEED named outlets if you have multiple outlets in the same COMPONENT. you should probably post more of this code tbh and what you're actually trying to accomplish as it looks like you're taking a questionable approach. named outlets were a mistake in angular IMO and should be avoided

Comment: @bryan60 totally agree, named outlets are confusing and to be honest I never used them. It just complicates stuff when a simple component loading will do just fine.

Comment: If I don't use named outlets, can I do something in the routes to make the URL read `/product/colours` instead of just `/colours`? I want to make it look like there's a parent -> child relationship.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `RouterLink` attribute, by default it routes to the primary router. You dont have a route `product/colours` on your primary router.

You have to let the `RouterLink` attribute know what outlet you want to use (if not the primary)

```html
<a 
  routerLinkActive="is-active" 
  [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { nested: ['colours'] } }]"
>
  Colours
</a>
```

You can find more on secondary route navigation in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#secondary-route-navigation-merging-routes-during-navigation)

Comment: This works! Is there a way to customise the URL so that it doesn't say `/product/(nested:colours)`?

Comment: There is no default way to do that, but I can see a potential way of doing it. If this answers your question, can you approve and upvote please :)

Answer (score -1):

i don't know what else you have going on that may be preventing you from doing this, but from the code presented here, you don't seem to have a need to use named outlets, so you could just do this in colours:

```
<a routerLinkActive="is-active" routerLink="colours">Colours</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and define the route without an outlet:

```
  {
    path: 'colours',
    component: ColoursComponent
  }
```